# Laravel route generation problem with APP_URL override

Tags: laravel

I have in .env file defined APP_URL. On apache web server host is configured to respond only for domain exampledomain.com

In routes is for example route defined as
Route::get('/orders/main-table', [\App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController::class, 'main_table'])->name('orders.offers_and_requests');

When following code is executed sometimes instead of expected url starting with https://exampledomain.com/...... I get https://ipaddress-of-server/.... and there is no rule  when I get this. I personaly can't replicate to get this result but sometimes like some hacker override this... I would't notice if I did't analyzed activity log as I for debug purposes log all activity in app... All these routes from which can be executed this url generation are protected, so hacker can't just use post to generate these links.

route('orders.offers_and_requests');

Comment: app_url has nothing to do with what URLs your web server will respond to.

Comment: @Snapey you didn’t read carefuly. question is not related to web server. question is how someone can override app_url in given example so instead of app_url to be generated something else for example ip address of server?

Comment: I read well I think. Anyone can type anything into a browser, or make curl requests to any IP.  What you do in your application or what setting you have in app_url is irrelevant. The Internet knows the IP of your server, as well as its name and will forward all the requests there.  Its then up to your web server application (apache) to decide if it should forward this request to your application.  Again, nothing within your app can affect that.